# Hive Udf (Encryption and Decryption) in Java

Tags: java, hadoop, encryption, hive

Actually i have written an Hive UDF in Java for Encryption and Decryption.
But it has some minor Bug in it. I couldn't find it, someone can  Please rectify and suggest me some changes..

### Problem:

```
 When i tried to execute this code using Hive it is showing some 'Null' columns for each
 row.
   Encrypted Ex:  1      fdfsvansjw=
                  NULL   NULL
                  2      adf4vandjw=
                  NULL   NULL

  Actually it has to be displayed without NULL Values.When i tried to decrypt the above
  data it is adding Newline Character '/n' in place of Null.
  Decrypted Ex:  1      AAA
                  /n    /n
                  2      BBB
                  /n     /n
```

### Code for Encryption :

```
package Encrypt;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import java.security.*;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public final class En1 extends UDF {

public Text evaluate(final Text s) throws Exception {
if (s == null) {
 return null;
}
byte[] sharedvector = {
0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x11
};

String EncText = "";
byte[] keyArray = new byte[24];
byte[] temporaryKey;
String key = "developersnotedotcom";
byte[] toEncryptArray = null;

//try
   // {

    toEncryptArray =  s.toString().getBytes("UTF-8");        
    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    temporaryKey = m.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));

    if(temporaryKey.length < 24) // DESede require 24 byte length key
    {
        int index = 0;
        for(int i=temporaryKey.length;i< 24;i++)
        {                   
            keyArray[i] =  temporaryKey[index];
        }
    }        

    Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");            
    c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyArray, "DESede"), new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));            
    byte[] encrypted = c.doFinal(toEncryptArray);            
    EncText = Base64.encodeBase64String(encrypted);


//  }
   /* catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException | UnsupportedEncodingException | NoSuchPaddingException | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException NoEx)
{
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NoEx);
     System.out.println(NoEx);
     System.exit(1);
}*/

return new Text(EncText.toString());        
}

}
```

### Input:

```
Actual I/p Ex:    1      AAA
                  2      BBB

Encrypted O/p Ex:     1      fdfsvansjw=
                      NULL   NULL
                      2      adf4vandjw=
                      NULL   NULL
```

### Code For Decryption :

```
package Encrypt;

import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.UDF;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FunctionTask;
import java.security.MessageDigest;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;

import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public final class Dec1 extends UDF {

public Text evaluate(final Text s) {
  if (s == null) {
    return null;
   }
  byte[] sharedvector = {
   0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x05, 0x07, 0x0B, 0x0D, 0x11
   };

String RawText = "";
byte[] keyArray = new byte[24];
byte[] temporaryKey;
String key = "developersnotedotcom";
byte[] toEncryptArray = null;

try
  {

    MessageDigest m = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        temporaryKey = m.digest(key.getBytes("UTF-8"));           

        if(temporaryKey.length < 24) // DESede require 24 byte length key
        {
            int index = 0;
            for(int i=temporaryKey.length;i< 24;i++)
            {                  
                keyArray[i] =  temporaryKey[index];
            }
        }

        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(keyArray, "DESede"), new IvParameterSpec(sharedvector));
        byte[] decrypted = c.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(s.toString()));    
        RawText = new String(decrypted, "UTF-8"); 
   }
   catch(Exception NoEx)
    {
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, NoEx);
     System.out.println(NoEx + "This is Udf error");
     System.exit(1);
    }

   return new Text(RawText.toString());        
}

}
```

### Input:

```
Decrypted I/p Ex:     1      fdfsvansjw=
                      NULL   NULL
                      2      adf4vandjw=
                      NULL   NULL

Decrypted o/p Ex:    1      AAA
                     /n     /n
                     2      BBB
                     /n     /n

There should'nt be any Null's or /n when encryption and decryption.
Tried to find out the bug. But can't find out.
Please Help me.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 2):

The cause is not related to the Hive.

The encrypted string is separated by CRLFs, so you should remove the `\r\n` at the end of your encryption method: `return new Text(EncText.toString().replaceAll("\r|\n", ""));`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Will Du, Your solution worked for me.

I've implemented [this](http://diginbigdata.blogspot.com/2017/01/hive-udf-example-encrypt-decrypt-data_28.html) encryption code and ran in to a similar issue.
Below change to the return line of `Encrypt` method did the trick.

Before:

```
return output;
```

After:

```
return output.replaceAll("\r|\n", "");
```

Comment: Please consider accepting his answer if it answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your UDF evaluates return type **Text** . Change return type from **Text to String** as Hive supports following String types :

```
STRING
VARCHAR (Note: Only available starting with Hive 0.12.0)
CHAR (Note: Only available starting with Hive 0.13.0)
```

please check the Hive datatypes
[link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Types#LanguageManualTypes-StringTypes)